# CassandraEntityBase in C# DataStax Driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I have a .net core application which persists data to a Cassandra instance through DataStax driver.

I have a base class for my Cassandra entities. Now if I want to take my TimeUUID type id into this base class, when inserting I get the error:

```
Some partition key parts are missing: id
```

Same approach works in EntityFramework. And also problem is not with my tables, connection or keyspace since when I carry the id field back to entty itself, it works.

My insert method

```
public void Insert<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase
{
    _mapper.Insert(entity);
}
```

My base class

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [Column(name: "id")]
    public  TimeUuid Id { get; private set; } = TimeUuid.NewId();
}
```

An entity class which inherits base class

```
[Table(Keyspace = "unimportant", Name = "irrelevant")]
public class Irrelevant : EntityBase
{
    //fields
}
```

Can you tell me what is problem ? Is there a way to declare a CassandraEntityBaseClass ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. It was intentional. In [PocoDataFactory.cs](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Mapping/PocoDataFactory.cs) Line 102 I found it:

```
return t.GetTypeInfo().GetProperties(PublicInstanceBindingFlags).Where(p => p.CanWrite);
```

What is CanWrite ?

> Gets a value indicating whether the property can be written to.

Source : [PropertyInfo.CanWrite Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite?view=netframework-4.8)

Since my property was readonly

```
public  TimeUuid Id { get; private set; } = TimeUuid.NewId();
```

I re-write my code(only to test) as below and it worked:

```
public  TimeUuid Id { get; set;}
```

I'll now choose to set my property during insert at repository or at object ctor.